# How to use the value returned from foreach in ng-repeat using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, html

I need to display the field seconddate if it is greater than firstdate, otherwise second field should not be displayed. The date format is in dd mmm yyyy (for eg, 22 Nov 2017). The function is returning true or false. But don't know how to pass this in ng-repeat. if i put this function in ng-if, it is return nothing. Any help would be appreciate. Below is the code:

```
Json:

GetDetails:
{
    Displaydetails:
    {
        employees: [
                {
                    "name" : "Anu",
                    "city" : "abc",
                    "firstdate" : "12 Dec 2004",
                    "seconddate" : "31 Nov 2014"
                },

                {
                    "name" : "Anu",
                    "city" : "abc",
                    "firstdate" : "12 Dec 2004",
                    "seconddate" : "31 Nov 2014"
                },

                {
                    "name" : "Anu",
                    "city" : "abc",
                    "firstdate" : "12 Dec 2004",
                    "seconddate" : "31 Nov 2014"
                },

                {
                    "name" : "Anu",
                    "city" : "abc",
                    "firstdate" : "12 Dec 2004",
                    "seconddate" : "31 Nov 2014"
                }

            ]
    }
}


HTML:

<div ngcontroller = "mycontroller as myctrl" ng-repeat="employee in myctrl.empdetails.employees">
    <div> 
        name
    </div>

    <div> 
        {{employee.name}}
    </div>

    <div> 
        city
    </div>

    <div> 
        {{employee.city}}
    </div>

    <div> 
        firstdate
    </div>

    <div> 
        {{employee.firstdate}}
    </div>
 <div  ng-if="employee.showdate()> 
    <div> 
        seconddate
    </div>

    <div ng-if="employee.keepgoing == true"> 
        {{employee.seconddate}}
    </div>
```

```
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function myController ($scope,$rootScope,myService)
{
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.initfunc = function()
    {
        myService.getempDetails().then(function()
        {
            ctrl.empdetails=myservice.empack;

        }

        ctrl.showdate =function()
        {
            var keepgoing = true;
            ctrl.dateval = ctrl.empdetails.employees;
            angular.forEach (dateval, function(value, key) 
            {
                var firstdateval = new Date (value.firstdate);
                var seconddaateval = new Date (value.seconddate);
                if(Date.parse(firstdateval) < Date.parse(seconddateval))
                {
                    keepgoing = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    keepgoing = false;

                }
            });
        }
    }
}

function myservice()
{
    this.getempDetails = function(req)
    {
        var request = {
            url:jsonfilepath,
           method: 'GET'
        }

        return this.makecall(request) . then(function(response)
        {
            var res = response.data;
            if(res)
            {
                this.empack = res.displaydetails.employees;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to show second date if it is greater than firstdate

**html :**

```
<div ng-if="myctrl.showdate(employee)"> 
    <div> 
        seconddate
    </div>

    <div ng-bind="employee.seconddate"></div>
</div>
```

`myctrl.showdate(employee)` will check seconddate display or not for each emploee

**js**

```
ctrl.initfunc = function()
{
    myService.getempDetails().then(function()
    {
        ctrl.empdetails=myservice.empack;

    }
}
ctrl.showdate = function(employee) {
    if (Date.parse(employee.firstdateval) < 
        Date.parse(employee.seconddateval)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can define `ctrl.showdate` function outside of  `ctrl.initfunc` function

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked out. I have one more query based on this date how to display all details in descending order. That is recent secon date details should be top and other details should below on top details. How to incorporate this value in in order filter